# Nested Cursors in Mysql problem with FETCH

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have the problem with my nested cursors in MySQL.

My second cursor only advances 1 single record of the first courses and then shows me message indicating. Below is a sample of the response from my Mysql Workbeanch.

```
OPEN queryLegalArticleSource;
    queryLegalArticleSource_LOOP : LOOP
        -- PARSED VARS
        FETCH queryLegalArticleSource INTO configTypeArticleTypeTwo;  
        -- ************************************
        -- VALIDATE PROCESS noMoreRows
        -- ************************************
        IF noMoreRowsTwo = 1 THEN
            CLOSE queryLegalArticleSource;
            LEAVE queryLegalArticleSource_LOOP;
        END IF;                        
        SELECT legalBodyId, companyIdSource, configTypeArticleTypeTwo, noMoreRowsTwo;
    END LOOP queryLegalArticleSource_LOOP;     
CLOSE queryLegalArticleSource;
```

[image: My response]

If I comment the FETCH line

```
-- FETCH queryLegalArticleSource INTO configTypeArticleTypeTwo;
```

Get all the results, but I do not have the variable I need.

[image]

Check if any cursor was closing it before, but apparently I have everything right.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to close the cursor after it is already closed. If no more rows=1 is true, it closes the cursor. Then exists the loop. Then tries to close the cursor again.

Comment: Finally it was not directly the problem, but it helped me better understand the algorithms of cursors in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `cursor`.  Swap the ordering, then use `LIMIT 1` on the `SELECT`.

(Caveat:  I am guessing at a lot of things because of missing declarations, etc.)

(Please consider using shorter 'names'; it is hard to see the flow for the verbose names.)

Comment: Self explaining names are so much nicer...

Comment: I think the same, better explanatory name

Comment: The problem si solved! Ty Guys!